# How to use lubridate as_datetime function in combination with dplyr mutate and case_when functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to manipulate a `dttm` variable to adjust for different time zones depending on a numeric id vector. I can manipulate the variable depending on the id without issues using a character vector as the new value. However, when I try to use the `date_time()` function to create the new value, each value receives the result of the first item in `case_when`.

The id vector is numeric and I have tried to convert the class to a factor and character. The issue pertains.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df1 <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  date_time = rep(as_datetime("2018-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "Europe/Zurich"), 3)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    date_time2 = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ "one",
      id == 2 ~ "two",
      TRUE ~ "three"
    )
  )


df2 <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  date_time = rep(as_datetime("2018-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "Europe/Zurich"), 3)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    date_time2 = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ as_datetime(date_time, tz = "America/New_York"),
      id == 2 ~ as_datetime(date_time, tz = "Asia/Kolkata"),
      TRUE ~ date_time
    )
  )

df3 <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  date_time = rep(as_datetime("2018-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "Europe/Zurich"), 3)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    date_time2 = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ as_datetime(date_time, tz = "Asia/Kolkata"),
      id == 2 ~ as_datetime(date_time, tz = "America/New_York"),
      TRUE ~ date_time
    )
  )


df1 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id date_time           date_time2
#>   <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>     
#> 1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 one       
#> 2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 two       
#> 3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 three

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id date_time           date_time2         
#>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 06:34:56
#> 2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 06:34:56
#> 3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 06:34:56

df3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id date_time           date_time2         
#>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:04:56
#> 2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:04:56
#> 3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:04:56
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

`df1` shows what I expect.

In `df2`, I expect `date_time2` at `id` == 2 to show "2018-01-01 17:04:56" and not "2018-01-01 06:34:56".

In `df3`, I expect `date_time2` at `id` == 3 to show "2018-01-01 12:34:56" and not "2018-01-01 17:04:56".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to a bug (probably of `dpylr`, since there had been issues with dates before).

Here is a possible work arround (don't ask me why it works :))

```
tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  date_time = rep(as_datetime("2018-01-01 12:34:56", tz = "Europe/Zurich"), 3)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    date_time2 = case_when(
      id == 1 ~ as_datetime(as.character(as_datetime(date_time, tz = "America/New_York"))),
      id == 2 ~ as_datetime(as.character(as_datetime(date_time, tz = "Asia/Kolkata"))),
      TRUE ~  as_datetime(as.character(date_time))

    )
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id date_time           date_time2         
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 06:34:56
2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:04:56
3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 12:34:56
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `force_tzs` from the `lubridate` package. We can provide different time zone settings to the `tzones` argument. In this case, `case_when` is not required if you know the order of time zones.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 %>%
  mutate(date_time2 = force_tzs(date_time, tzones = c("America/New_York", "Asia/Kolkata", "UTC")))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id date_time           date_time2         
#   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:34:56
# 2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 07:04:56
# 3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 12:34:56

df3 %>%
  mutate(date_time2 = force_tzs(date_time, tzones = c("Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York", "UTC")))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      id date_time           date_time2         
#   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1     1 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 07:04:56
# 2     2 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 17:34:56
# 3     3 2018-01-01 12:34:56 2018-01-01 12:34:56
```

Comment: You could index a vector of timezones with the `id` in case there are more values than in the reprex. 
Do you know, why you get `07:04:56` instead of `06:34:56` for Kolkata? Is that some kind of summer time issue?

Comment: Thanks. As suggested by @kath, I have a few hundred ids and indexing is helpful in this case. However, the solution suggested below works perfectly despite that I struggle to understand why. The timezone for India is 4:30 ahead of CET during winter time and 5:30 during summer time.